# Inter scipt/process communication in php

Tags: php, queue, ipc

I am developing a queue that requires communication between a php page and a php script. What I am having a difficult time with is understanding what would be a good path to take. In my queue, a user will generate a `task` on a php page, and a php script has to obtain that `task` and process it in a queue type fashion. I have read up that the following methods exist:

- **Normal files:** My understanding is that the php page would create a file in a directory, while the php script would search for files in that directory and then use the information in those files to execute tasks.
- **Sockets:** still fuzzy understanding. Something to do with sending information to a port that a script would be listening to.
- **Pipes:** still fuzzy.
- **Tcp Connections:** very fuzzy understanding.
- **Shared memory:** not sure how different files would share memory. This seems very interesting, though I have no idea how it is implemented!

**QUESTION:** Which of these options (or any other option I am missing in my list) would you appropriate for inter script communication in php for my particular case and why? **Note:** The queue would probably be very active, receiving 1 task every second.

All feedback is greatly appreciated!

Comment: We use Beanstalk queues for this in our applications. The Beanstalk server hides all the details.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a good question for the StackExchange model of Q/A. There are likely to be arguments for and against each method, and no definitive answer. That's why opinion-based questions are considered off-topic.

Comment: @Barmar I have taken your advice and have been trying to install beanstalkd for a few days now with little success: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37307756/installing-with-the-linux-terminal

Comment: @Barmar I have managed to install beanstalkd on a LAMP stack I made on my computer, and am really close in getting it to work, could you possibly let me know what I have missing here?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37356427/unable-to-get-beanstalkd-queue-to-work

Comment: @Barmar haha sorry If Im asking you too many questions dude. I'm like soo close to getting pheanstalk to work. I think this might be the last thing I'm having an issue with. Getting an error with the pheanstalk class: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37368944/fatal-error-class-pheanstalk-pheanstalk-not-found