# Installing beanstalkd on a shared hosting account at Godaddy

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, installation, beanstalkd

I am trying to install **beanstalkd** (http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/download.html) via the Linux Terminal **on a shared hosting account at Godaddy**.

The previous link gives commands that should install **beanstalkd** on the server. I use SSH (with PuTTy) to access the Linux Terminal.  I have practically tried all the commands in the previous link and am consistently obtaining errors like:

```
sudo apt-get install beanstalkd
```

error message: `-bash: sudo: command not found`

```
brew install beanstalkd
```

error message: `-bash: brew: command not found`

```
su -c 'rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-3.noarch.rpm'
su -c 'yum install beanstalkd --enablerepo=epel-testing'
```

error message: `-bash: su: command not found`

```
yaourt -S beanstalkd
```

error message: `-bash: yaourt: command not found`

I am not even sure what `bash` is exactly and if it is causing the problem, or if its because I'm using an SSH connection, or if it's really because the commands don't actually exist on the server (which would be strange because when I do `man sudo` or `man su` I do in fact get the complete manual of both commands in the terminal).

**QUESTION:** Why am I unable to run the previous commands to install **beanstalkd** on the linux server? Does it have to do with me using PuTTy (ssh connection)? What could I possibly do to get **beanstalkd** installed? Could it be because its shared hosting with Godaddy, and I might not have full power over the linux terminal?

**SERVER INFO:** When running `cat /proc/version` I obtain my linux distribution: `Red Hat 4.4.7-16`. I have a shared hosting account with Godaddy with a linux server hosting my site.

Comment: I wonder if you're copy-pasting a weird character.  Try typing `sudo echo hi` by hand.

Comment: @SLaks I tried it just now, same error `-bash: sudo: command not found`

Comment: maybe you overwrote your shell somehow... Can you start a new one with `bash`? What does `type bash` gives?

Comment: @J.Chomel when runing `type bash` I get: `bash is /bin/bash`

Comment: what about `type sudo`?

Comment: with `type sudo` I get `-bash: type: sudo: not found`

Comment: @J.Chomel I'm thinkingi t might be some configuration file. I found 1 post that might be relevant: https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/ssh-access-not-working-for-root.63014/

Comment: @J.Chomel though the instructions given by the "PartnerNOC" below don't seem to appear in godaddy (post was made in 2003, ages ago)

Answer (score 1):

You have a RedHat distro, and they use rpm+yum for package management.

I see from `yum search beanstalkd` on my box that I can find it, but only on [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL).

However, you have a really old version of RedHat, so can't just install the epel-release rpm, also, there doesn't seem to be a built version for RedHat 4.

If you had at least RedHat 5 you could do:

```
$ sudo yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-5.noarch.rpm
$ sudo yum install beanstalkd
```

Comment: do you think their might be an option for my version of RedHat distro? Odd godaddy maintains a really old version and hasn't updated.

Comment: also would version 4 of redhad cause the error for sudo: `-bash: sudo: command not found`? I would assume the sudo command existed in version 4

Answer (score 0):

You may in fact have a [restricted instance of batch](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/restricting-unix-users)...

You must go to your provider's interface and do the necessary to have `root` access. Have you tried something like explained here?

https://uk.godaddy.com/help/enable-adminroot-access-managed-or-fully-managed-12270

If it doesn't work for you, you may also try asking https://serverfault.com/ that seems more relevant for your case.

Comment: I was actually on that site previously, however I have not found the My Servers control panel. It is possible that I don't have this panel since I have a shared hosting account, though It's also possible I just couldn't find it. I will contact my hosting provider and see what they say. Once I do so I'll come back here and let you all know what new info was obtained.