# Fatal Error: Class 'Pheanstalk\Pheanstalk` not found

Tags: php, composer-php, pheanstalk

I am using a library that I downloaded with composer called Pheanstalk. I am running the following script:

```
<?php

//... some unrelated code

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');        //loading the autoload file from composer
use Pheanstalk\Pheanstalk;                  //using the namespace
$pheanstalk = new Pheanstalk('127.0.0.1');  //initiating an object

//... some unrelated code

?>
```

The following error appears:

```
Fatal Error: Class 'Pheanstalk\Pheanstalk' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/project_zero/index.php on line 16
```

with line 16 being: `$pheanstalk = new Pheanstalk('127.0.0.1');`

**Question:** Why might I be getting this error? The script above was basically copy-paisted from the **Usage Example** given on the Pheanstalk github page: https://github.com/pda/pheanstalk.

The contents of my `composer.json` file are:

```
{
  "require": {
    "pda/pheanstalk": "2.1.1"
  }
}
```

---

EDITED:

New errors when using:

```
use \Pheanstalk_Pheanstalk
```

Errors:

```
Warning: The use statement with non-compound name 'Pheanstalk_Pheanstalk' has no effect in /opt/lampp/htdocs/project_zero/index.php on line 14

Fatal error: Class 'Pheanstalk' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/project_zero/index.php on line 17
```

Comment: `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: @Arcesilas do I run that in the terminal and give you the output? I'm relatively new to linux and composer

Comment: Just run it in terminal and retry.

Comment: It should be run automatically by composer when installing a new package, though.

Comment: @Arcesilas I just ran it in the terminal in the location of the composer.json file, the output was: `Generating autoload files`. I tried runing the script again, same error appeared

Comment: I noticed that some people use: `use Pheanstalk_Pheanstalk` in some online articles, though when I tried switching my `use Pheanstalk\Pheanstalk` with that, I got a different error

Comment: @Arcesilas I have a feeling that it might have something to do with my `composer.json` file and the version or it's format. I updated my question with it's contents. Do you happen to see anything wrong with it?

Comment: The code is PSR-4 compliant, so you actually have to use actual namespace: `use Pheanstalk\Pheanstalk;`

Comment: Ah! Version 2.1.1 :) See: https://github.com/pda/pheanstalk/blob/2.1/classes/Pheanstalk/Pheanstalk.php Class name is actually: `class Pheanstalk_Pheanstalk implements Pheanstalk_PheanstalkInterface`

Comment: When you use a composer package, don't forget to mention the version... Default behaviour is to consider you use the latest.

Comment: @Arcesilas lol sorry i'm newish to classes in php, would I then use: `use Pheanstalk_Pheanstalk implements Pheanstalk_PheanstalkInterface` instead or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your `composer.json`, you are using version 2.1.1: https://github.com/pda/pheanstalk/blob/2.1/classes/Pheanstalk/Pheanstalk.php

The class name is `Pheanstalk_Pheanstalk` not `Pheanstalk\Pheanstalk`: it was not PSR-4 compliant at this moment.

So you should just use:

```
<?php
use \Pheanstalk_Pheanstalk;
```

when you're in a namespaced file. If you don't use namespace in a file, you don't need to "import" the class.

Backslash is important if you use namespaces, because the class, in version 2.x was not namespaced.

**UPDATE**

So your code should be like this:

```
<?php

//... some unrelated code

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');        //loading the autoload file from composer
$pheanstalk = new Pheanstalk_Pheanstalk('127.0.0.1');  //initiating an object

//... some unrelated code

?>
```

That's all.

Comment: So I would have to change `user Pheanstalk\Pheanstalk` to  `use Pheanstalk_Pheanstalk`? Because I previously mentioned in the comments I tried that and got another error hahah. I'll try again though and post If I get an error

Comment: Edited it again :)

Comment: hahah got a new error now, I edited my answer with the errors that I'm getting with the previous modification. I tried using the \ and without the \ also

Comment: As I said: if you don't use namespace, you don't need to import the class. No namespace in your file, no need to use `use Pheanstalk_Pheanstalk`.

Comment: You mean instead of using a namespace, to put all the class inside the same file?

Comment: No. I mean: if you use "namespace My\Awesome\Application` then you need to "import" the class with `use \Pheanstalk_Pheanstalk`. If you don't use a namespace, you don't need: just use your class in your code.

Comment: I'm completely new to using classes and namespaces lol, sorry if they are stupid questions

Comment: You might consider reading the documentation about [namespaces in PHP](http://php.net/namespace)

Comment: ok so the modification to my code that i need for it to work would be to take out `use \Pheanstalk_Pheanstalk` and put in something else?

Comment: Updated it once again, with your example corrected.

Comment: Worked! your a genius, thanks man. I'll also read the documentation on namespaces to get up to date. Hopefully I can find out later why the namespace code didn't work.

Comment: I'm not a genius, just a long time user :) Glad  I could help!

Comment: The namespace does work: with PSR-4 compliant code, which is the case for version 3 of this package. Version 2.1 is only PSR-0 compliant, which does not use namespaces.

Comment: Oh so if I understood you correctly, literally in my specific case it was not working because I was using a namespace when the version of the pheanstalk library I had installed wasn't compliant with the necessities to be using namespaces in the first place?

Comment: That's it. You were using example given for version 3. Switching to branch 2.1 of the code: https://github.com/pda/pheanstalk/tree/2.1 would have given you the correct instructions (which are in your files, in `README.md`)

Comment: Nice. Thanks for taking the time to debug the issue. life saver.

Comment: Hey dude, I created another question regarding pheanstalk. If I could have your feedback that would be awesome! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370688/pheanstalk-and-beanstalk-functions